# yii what are the difference between begincontent() renderpartial()?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

They seem to be doing the same thing: they are passing layouts to a view.
I am new to Yii and I do not know what the difference is. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: Do you simply mean the difference between versions 1.1 and 2.0? If so, perhaps [this post](http://www.brihaspatitech.com/blog/switching-to-yii2-0/) will provide answers...

Comment: I mean those two functions.

Answer (score 0):

`renderPartial()` - renders a named view without any layout. If you don't have any layout and want to render a named view  (a view previously stored for reuse) you can use `renderPartial()`.

`beginContent()` - is for managing nested layout. Inside a layout you can  reuse a named view like a nested layout .

See [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html) for a brief guide.